# send data into multiple array in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]i want to send change the value "false" in mentions-->"rcs"--> "visible" into multiple array in json
Im new in angular and i don t know how i can manage that so try that but it s not working. Can you help me ?

in my json array there is an object called "mentions" and in this object an array with an other object called "rcs" (at the end of the file) and there is the line "visible" which is a boolean . I want to change this boolean to "true" because it is currently "false"

Here is my json :

```
 "data": {
    "company_name": "Laplagem",
    "entrepreneur_firstname": "guillaumO",
    "entrepreneur_lastname": "nouveaunomF",
    "login": "gui.nouhaud@gmail.com",
    "company_address": "120 rue de la pacrette fraiche",
    "company_zipcode": "78630",
    "company_city": "Pignons sur rue",
    "company_country": "France",
    "company_phone": "0123435522",
    "activity_type": "V",
    "declaration_period": "M",
    "activity_start": "2016-02-01",
    "company_siret": "53106089500020",
    "rcs_city": "Paris",
    "naf_code": "",
    "has_accre": false,
    "invoice_header": "Laplagem\nguillaumO nouveaunomF\n120 rue de la pacrette fraiche\n78630 Pignons sur rue\ngui.nouhaud@gmail.com\n0123435522",
    "invoice_footer": "SIRET : 53106089500020 - RCS : Paris",
    "invoice_payment_delay": "60",
    "bank_balance": 0,
    "mentions": {
      "vat": {
        "value": "TVA non applicable, art. 293 B du CGI",
        "visible": true,
        "alwaysVisible": true,
        "alterable": false
      },
      "delay": {
        "value": "En cas de retard de paiement, une pénalité de 3 fois le taux d’intérêt légal sera appliquée, à laquelle s’ajoutera une indemnité forfaitaire pour frais de recouvrement de 40€",
        "visible": true,
        "alwaysVisible": true,
        "alterable": true
      },
      "free": {
        "value": "Ma nouvelle mention perso",
        "visible": true,
        "alwaysVisible": false,
        "alterable": true
      },
      "bank": {
        "value": "",
        "visible": true,
        "alwaysVisible": false,
        "alterable": true
      },
      "cga": {
        "value": "Membre d’une association agréée, le règlement des honoraires par chèque est accepté",
        "visible": true,
        "alwaysVisible": false,
        "alterable": true
      },
      "rcs": {
        "value": "Dispensé d’immatriculation au registre du commerce et des sociétés (RCS)",
        "visible": false,
        "alwaysVisible": false,
        "alterable": true
      }
    }
  }.
```

Here is my controller :

```
$scope.valuercs = function(){
  var mytoken = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
  var transform = {"mentions":{"rcs": {"value" : "true"}} };
  factovalrcs.send(mytoken, transform).then(function(conf){
    console.log(conf);
  });
}
```

Here my service :

```
.factory('factovalrcs', ['$http','$q', function ($http,$q){
      var newdata = {};
      newdata.send = function(mytoken, transform){
       var deferred = $q.defer();
       $http({
           method: 'POST',
           url: "http://api.tiime-ae.fr/0.1/request/settings-update.php",
           headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
           transformRequest: function(obj) {
               var str = [];
               for(var p in obj)
               str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
               return str.join("&");
           },
           data: {token: mytoken, transform}
           })
           .success(function(conf){

              deferred.resolve(conf);

              // var promise = deferred.promise;
              // promise.then(function(result){
              // var  mydata = result["data"];
              // console.log(mydata);
              //   }
              //);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
           };
           return newdata;
}])
```

Comment: "i want to send change the value "false" in mentions-->"rcs"--> "value" into multiple array in json" - could you rephrase or explain that? I don't understand.

Comment: You see in my json array there is an object called "mentions" and in this object an array with an other object called "rcs" and there is the line "visible" which is a boolean . I want to change this boolean to "true" because it is currently "false"

Comment: `conf.data.mentions.rcs.visible = true;`, however you need to assign `conf` to the scope somewhere.

Comment: I m sorry but i don t know how can i use your line : conf.data.mentions.rcs.visible = true;

Comment: in `factovalrcs.send(mytoken, transform).then(function(conf){...}`

Comment: I'm sorry but does someone can redact an answer because it still not working :( ( I m new in angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply assign to `$scope.valuercs`, because your AJAX call is asynchronous. You need to toggle the `visible` bit in the success function and also assign the result to `$scope.valuercs`:

```
  var mytoken = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
  var transform = {"mentions":{"rcs": {"value" : "true"}} };
  factovalrcs.send(mytoken, transform).then(function(conf){
    console.log(conf);
    conf.data.mentions.rcs.visible = true;
    console.log(conf);
    $scope.valuercs = conf;
  });
```

Comment: Ok i understand ! but the only thing is that the json is get from an API so i really need to change the value of the json. So to do that i need to send the request in POST with my service how can i do that ( related to my service i showed you)

Comment: The code is still using your `factovalrcs` service.

Comment: Sure but i mean changing this line :  data: {token: mytoken, transform} of my service to post the request

Comment: Sorry you need to write a bit more detailed comments, I don't understand what you are trying to say. Are you trying to use a different value for `transform` or do you want to add something to `data`? The service uses POST after all. Do you want to set `transform.mentions.rcs.visibility` to true?

Comment: sorry if i don t explain myself very well. I want to set mentions.rcs.visible to true. If i follow your code i have this error : "Cannot read property 'rcs' of undefined"

Comment: In my code, there's a `console.log(conf);` right before the line `conf.data.mentions.rcs.visible = true;`. Could you fully expand the object in the browser developer tools and append it as a screenshot to your question? The error "Cannot read property 'rcs' of undefined" means that `mentions` does not exist in the data - however it does exist in the data from your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106266/discussion-between-guillaume-nouhaud-and-johannes-jander).